# save results of each iteration

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

Hello I am new to python and I need to get the output of each iteration from the for loop. I am running two for loops. I need to get the output of 2nd for loop separately so that I can plot the entire graph in single window. At present I am getting the outputs separately. Can anyone help me how to resolve the issue?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

x= [2,6,9,12]
y= [3,7,12,18]
T= [0,4,5,8]

x_s= x[0]
y_s= y[0]

v_f= 0
N= 3

for i in range(N):
    v_i = 0

    a3= []
    a4= []
    a5= []

    for j in range(T[i]):
        a0= x[j]
        a1= v_i

        X= np.array([[1,T[j],T[j]**2],
                     [1,T[j+1],T[j+1]**2],
                     [0,1,2*T[j]]])

        A= np.array([x[j],x[j+1],v_i])

        c1= np.linalg.solve(X,A)
        a0= c1[0]
        a1= c1[1]
        a2= c1[2]

        v_i= a1 + 2*a2*T[j+1]

        t= np.linspace(T[j],T[j+1])

        print( a0,a1,a2)
        print (v_i)

        a3.append(a0)
        a4.append(a1)
        a5.append(a2)

        xr= a0 + a1*t + a2*t**2

        f1=plt.figure()
        ax = f1.add_subplot(232)

        ax.plot(t,xr)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. It is doing something different now.

Comment: Save plotting values (t,xr) in list and then  plot using those values

Comment: I have correceted the indent but still I am getting three separate graphs. I need to save the output of each iterations so that I can plot the graphs at once. Can you please help.

Comment: I tried to save the values of xr as list also but its not reading the values from the iterations. I am not able to find out the issue.

Comment: Put the `f1=plt.figure()` and `ax=f1.add_subplot()` lines before your `for` loop and the `plt.show()` line after your `for` loop, then everything will be in the same figure.

Comment: I tried to use it @ThomasKühn but now I am getting the graph of only first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you run that exact code ? I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 36, in <module>
    [1,T[j+1],T[j+1]**2],

IndexError: list index out of range
```

In any case, you need to put the `plt.figure()` and the `plt.show()` before and after the `for loop`, respectively, but outside (mind the indentation). Otherwise you create a new figure at each iteration, and put on this figure the subplot associated to this iteration.

Comment: If you solved the issue using this code, please accept the answer such that people having same will find the answer rapidly. Otherwise, please answer to your own question and accept your own answer.